# Contar as palavras mais populares

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando encontrar o número de ocorrências de uma lista de palavras em um texto:

```
from collections import Counter

def popularidade (texto, palavras):

    texto = texto.lower().split()
    palavras = palavras.lower().split()

    lista = []

    for p in palavras:
        for t in texto:
            if p == t:
                lista.append(t)
                return Counter(lista)

print(popularidade("Ao nos resolver a esta tarefa, preste nos atenção nos seguintes a nos pontos:", "nos, a, preste"))
```

Resultado:

> Counter({'preste': 1})

Resultado desejado:

> {'nos': 4, 'a': 2, 'preste': 1}

Comment: Você está retornando da função sempre na primeira palavra encontrada. Tente retirar o retorno de dentro do laço de repetição. Para compreender melhor o que o seu código faz, faça o teste de mesa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na realidade há duas coisa que te estão a passar despercebidas,

O return faz com que a função retorne (pare a execução) logo após essa linha, e há um pormenor que te está a escapar, as virgulas das palavras, o que fazem com que a verificação não retorne true, ex: `'nos' == 'nos,' = False`.

O teu código corrigido:

```
from collections import Counter

def popularidade (texto, palavras):

    texto = texto.lower().split()
    palavras = palavras.lower().replace(',', '').split() # tirar virgulas

    lista = []

    for p in palavras:
        for t in texto:
            if p == t:
                lista.append(t)
    return Counter(lista) # return quando todas as palavras verificadas

print(popularidade("Ao nos resolver a esta tarefa, preste nos atenção nos seguintes a nos pontos:", "nos a preste"))
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/QisQac)

Para dizer a verdade nem precisas de 'tanto a acontecer', nem do `Counter()`:

```
palavras = "nos, a, preste"
texto = "Ao nos resolver a esta tarefa, preste nos atenção nos seguintes a nos pontos:"
palavras_spl = palavras.lower().replace(',', '').split()
text_spl = texto.lower().split()
count = {p: text_spl.count(p) for p in palavras_spl if p in text_spl}
print(count) # {'preste': 1, 'a': 2, 'nos': 4}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/qWebkc)

Sequiseres remover por completo a pontuação de ambos, de maneira a assegurar que ambos ficam apenas com palavras:

```
import string

palavras = "nos, a, preste"
texto = "Ao nos resolver a esta tarefa, preste nos atenção nos seguintes a nos pontos:"

palavras_spl = palavras.translate(palavras.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)).lower().split()
text_spl = texto.translate(texto.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)).lower().split()
count = {p: text_spl.count(p) for p in palavras_spl if p in text_spl}
print(count) # {'preste': 1, 'a': 2, 'nos': 4}
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/tM3fmr)

Comment: Apesar do exemplo do OP não contemplar essas questões, acredito que pontuações no texto original também possam afetar o resultado (e.g., `tarefa,` vs `tarefa`). Recomendo limpar as pontuações: `texto_limpo = texto.translate(None, string.punctuation)`.

Comment: É verdade @AnthonyAccioly, boa dica, não me lembrei . obgado, vou completar com essa info

Answer (score 2):

```
def frequencia(texto):
    frequencia_por_palavra = [texto.count(p) for p in texto]
    return dict(zip(texto, frequencia_por_palavra))

def popularidade(texto, palavras):
    dFrequencia = frequencia(texto)
    return dict((k, dFrequencia[k]) for k in palavras if k in dFrequencia)

print(popularidade(open('texto.txt').read().split(), ['filhos', 'amada']))
```

texto.txt contém o hino brasileiro

Resultado:

```
{'amada': 4, 'filhos': 2}
```

## Opção 2

Se você gosta de expressões regulares, pode também fazer assim:

```
def popularidade(texto, palavra):
    import re
    return sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(palavra), texto))

palavras = "nos, a, preste"
texto = "Ao nos resolver a esta tarefa, preste nos atenção nos seguintes a nos pontos:"
d = dict( (v, popularidade(texto, v)) for v in palavras.split(",") )
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Temos dois problemas ai amigo.

1. A identação do código está errada na linha do seu return. Ele deveria estar referenciado ao 1º 'FOR' e não ao IF, para que ele possa retornar somente após o preenchimento total da sua lista
2. Como você possui virgulas junto as palavras no momento do Split ele separa as palavras juntamente com as vírgulas (`palavra = ['nos,' , 'a,' , 'preste' ]` ), devido a isso ele não encontra essas palavras no texto.

O código correto nesse caso seria:

```
from collections import Counter

def popularidade (texto, palavras):

    texto = texto.lower().split()

    palavras = palavras.lower().split()


    lista = []

    for p in palavras:
        for t in texto:
            if p == t:
                lista.append(t)

    return Counter(lista)

print(popularidade("Ao nos resolver a esta tarefa, preste nos atenção nos seguintes a nos pontos:", "nos a preste"))
```

> Resultado:
>       Counter({'nos': 4, 'a': 2, 'preste': 1})